# Accessing methods in another class

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, superclass

I have a class Worker which I want to access methods from hive, garden and all the subclasses of the superclass flower. A worker is in an arraylist in hive which is in a garden and the garden also has an arraylist of flowers. I have accessed the methods from hive using the constructor:

```
public worker(Hive hive){
    this.hive= hive
}
```

And I want to access the method findFlower() from the garden to get a flower and extractPollen() (which every type of flower inherits from the super class flower) from the flowers I get to get pollen from them. Do I need to make more constructors for garden and for each type of flower or will 2 constructors, 1 for the garden and 1 for the super constructor flower work?

My code so far:

```
public class Worker extends Bee {

    Hive hive = null; 
    public Garden garden;
    public Flower flower;

    public Worker(Hive hive){
        this.hive=hive;
        this.type = 2;
        this.age=11;
        this.health=3;
    }

    public Bee anotherDay(){
        flower= garden.findFlower();
        flower.extractPollen(int);
        eat();
        age++; 
    }
}

public class Garden{

    ArrayList<Flower> flowerbed = new ArrayList<Flower>();

    public Flower findFlower(){
        //code which returns a random flower from my arraylist
    }
}

public class Flower{

    public boolean extractPollen(int po){
        if(po <= pollen){
            pollen= pollen - po;
            return true;
        }return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May i suggest this...

A worker can't "work" without both a Hive or Garden. Supply both. Also, flower doesnt need to be a member variable. Its local to anotherDay().  Also, anotherDay() need not return Bee. The caller has reference to your object anyway.

```
public class Worker extends Bee {
    private Hive hive;
    private Garden garden;

    public Worker(Hive hive, Garden garden){
        super(hive);
        this.hive=hive;
        this.garden = garden;
        this.type = 2;
        this.age=11;
        this.health=3;
    }

    public void anotherDay(){
        Flower flower = garden.findFlower();
        flower.extractPollen(/* some value */);
        eat();
        age++;
    }
}
```

Another approach is that Hive and Garden are not members at all, but are passed in for each methed call. eg `anotherDay(Garden garden);`  the benefits of this are that your worker can roam gardens. The drawback is that the calling code has to manage the Garden object. These are the trade offs you make as you do OO design :)

Comment: I should have put in my question that there was some code omitted. The another day method needs to return a bee as after a certain number of days the worker will change into another type of bee. The constructor must also be `public Worker(Hive hive)` as a superclass has that constructor and most of the other subclasses in said superclass need the Hive hive constructor and do not need the garden at all. The anotherDay method is also inherited and the other subclasses which have it would not make sense to take a garden as a paramater!! Thanks for the help so far

Comment: hmm.. regarding anotherDay() returning Bee. If the method is on an instance of Bee, the return value can only be "this" or another Bee instance all together. I understand you have been given this code to work with, but its not a very good design. The caller would be expected to know that a new Bee may be returned and stop calling the Bee reference it already had.

Comment: Just a note: Object Inheritance has proven to be much over rated and causes more problems than it solves. There are many articles and opinions on this. The same "results" can be achieved using composition and interfaces. Anyway, I don't mean to start a big discussion about this here. Only to make the point that if you have been given a certain class hierarchy and its not suiting what you need, its not your fault. :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the help- everything compiles but unfortunately now when I run my code I get a nullpointerexception. Do you know why this is?

Comment: the stack trace should let you know where that happened. In your above code you have a private Garden garden; but nothing ever sets is.

Comment: Nothing ever sets is- could be my brain getting tired but I'm struggling to understand that? The stack trace says that it is from the line ` Flower flower = garden.findFlower();` From my understanding that means that either flower or garden is null? Using system.out.println I know that there is at least 1 flower in my garden so does that mean that there is something wrong with my garden?

Comment: garden is null and the cause of the error. it was never created and by default will be null. you'll need to assign it somewhere.  private Garden garden = new Garden(); might do the trick :) im not sure how gardens are constructed though. This is what I was saying about passing in the reference via the constructor.  The Worker class shouldn't be responsible for creating it. Also, every new Worker instance will create a new and separate Garden instance, which isnt what you want. I assume there is only 1 (or a few) Gardens

Comment: JustBrenkman's answer is a singleton pattern. calling Garden.getInstance() will return 1 and only ever 1 garden.

Comment: Now I am getting the error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Garden.getRandomInteger(Garden.java:46)
 at Garden.findFlower(Garden.java:51)
 at Worker.anotherDay(Worker.java:17)
 at Hive.anotherDay(Hive.java:104)
 at TestBasicHive.testpart5(TestBasicHive.java:407)
 at TestBasicHive.main(TestBasicHive.java:14)`

I am using a getRandomInteger method which uses the import java.util.Random; but that was working absolutely fine until I tried Garden.getInstance()- what has caused the error?

Comment: you have commented out "code which returns a random flower from my arraylist" - but the error is that a non positive number is being passed to Random.nextInt() - i suspect that a Garden needs to be initialised properly. I'm it's because there are no flowers in the garden. Random.nextInt() is probably being called with the size of the  flower list which would be zero.

Comment: In the test harness I wrote I add flowers like this: `     Bee b;
     Flower f;
     Flower f2;
     Garden g = new Garden();
     Hive h = new Hive();
     h = new Hive();
     b = new Queen(h);
     f = new Daffodil();
     f2= new Rose();
     g.addFlower(f2);
     h.addHoney(100);
     int i;
     h.addBee(b);
     g.addFlower(f);
     g.addFlower(f);`
Does this not add flowers to the garden? I think it used to but I'm not sure with the garden instance thing now

Comment: You might be setting up a garden with all the flowers, but isn't the instance of garden that Worker can access. Again, this is why I was saying it needs to be passed in. Have fun :)

Comment: Do you know how I could pass it in?

Answer (score 1):

You could try;

```
public class Garden {

    ArrayList<Flower> flowerbed = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    private static Garden instance;

    public Flower findFlower(){
        //code which returns a random flower from my arraylist
   }

    public static Garden getInstance() {
         if (instance == null) {
              instance = new Garden();
         }
         return instance;
     }
}
```

This will return an instance of Garden and allow you to access findFlower with

```
Garden.getInstance().findFlower();
```

When you call the getInstance() for the first time it will create a new Garden

Comment: i think you forgot the "static" in "private Garden instance;" :)